# android: constantly update information from web server in background

Tags: android, database, loops, background, webserver

So i'm working on an app that needs to retrieve constantly updating database information and display it on a map using markers and locations.

How would I go about creating an infinite loop in the background that retrieves the information after a set interval.

I'm not looking for a service that constantly runs in the background, just something that updates while the app is open and the data is viewable.

I know how to do everything to do with map fragments its just creating an infinite loop in the background that I cant figure out.

Comment: Use ScheduledExecutorService. https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use a async task and then start it from the background thread in a given interval.

I will recommend that your app don't call the database directly but you create some kind of backend. Then you can cache stuff and put some load off the app.